# Why my jQuery UI is not working?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I build my site with joomla and I check my HTML head, jquery ui has been loaded, but I still can't use its methods like `effect()`, what could possibly be wrong?

Here is a [screen capture](http://w.nycweb.io/jui.html).

Comment: do you load jquery first before jquery-ui ? try typing `$` in the console. it must return a function

Comment: You can see from my video jQuery is in the first `<script>` tag. instead of `j`, I also tried `jQuery`, it still doesn't work.

Comment: There may be another Script interfering. You have a lot loaded there.